# Error Message for Bower

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I'm trying to run bower install --save angular-ui-calendar  but I get the response zsh: command not found: bower.  So then I run
npm config set prefix /usr/local (which works)
npm install -g bower  (which gives me the following error message.)
Thanks a lot!

```
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib
/usr/local/lib
└── bower@1.7.9
npm ERR! Linux 4.2.0-18-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/opt/nvm/versions/node/v4.2.1/bin/node"    "/usr/local/opt/nvm/versions/node/v4.2.1/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "bower"
npm ERR! node v4.2.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib']
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/nitrous/FV/npm-debug.log
```

Comment: you lack permission to write into `/usr/local/lib` directory. Either use `sudo npm` or `chmod` change the access level to the `usr/local/lib` directory (possibly with `sudo`)

Comment: It says sudo: npm: command not found  Thanks for the response! @Caleb

Comment: It says sudo: npm: command not found Thanks for the response!  @Yerken